# Check for dates consistency in MATLAB

Tags: validation, matlab, datetime, date

Is there any straight forward way to do that? I want to give an array of dates as an input (for example 1997-01-02 1997-01-03... using the format yyyy-mm-dd) and get 1 if all the elements of the given array are consistent and 0 otherwise.

Any idea?

Comment: what do you mean by consistent?  All within the same time period?  All "legal" dates (there is nothing like 1998-13-13 for example)?  Help us out and we will help you out.

Comment: Exactly! I am talking about "legal" dates. Two posts bellow, there is a very good answer from Amro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one idea:

```
d = {
    '1997-01-02'
    '1997-01-03'
    '1111-99-99'
    'not a date'
}

isDateValid = false(size(d));
for i=1:numel(d)
    try
        str = datestr(datenum(d{i},'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd');
        isDateValid(i) = isequal(str,d{i});
    catch ME
    end
end
```

The result:

```
>> isDateValid
isDateValid =
     1
     1
     0
     0
```

The reason I do the conversion back and forth is that MATLAB will carry values outside the normal range of fields to the next one -- third example will actually be parsed as: `1119-06-07`. While the last one will throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this using regexp. A couple of simple ones:

```
str = '1917-01-23';

regexp(str,'\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d')
ans =
     1
```

If the string matches exactly that pattern, you will get 1, else empty.

Or do this:

```
regexp(str,'-','split')
ans = 
    '1917'    '01'    '23'
```

Now you can verify the first piece is a valid year, the second a valid month, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I want.